# Superposition of sidebar menu

Tags: html, css, adminlte

I have a menu item, having submenus, which I want to put in another menu item. That is as multilevel sidebar items. But there is overlapping as seen on the following image. How can it be fixed?

I expect XYZ, A,B, and C. to shift toward bottom.

[image]

```
  <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
        <nav class="mt-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">

              
                <div id="theModal" class="modal fade text-center">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">

                        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-swatchbook"></i>
                        <p>
                            Servis
                            <i class="fas fa-angle-left right"></i>
                        </p>
                    </a>

                    <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="serviceorder" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="nav-icon far fa-image"></i>
                                <p>
                                    Q
                                </p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="vehicleinservice" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="nav-icon fas fa-edit"></i>
                                <p>
                                    W
                                </p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="servicehistory" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="nav-icon far fa-image"></i>
                                <p>
                                    P
                                </p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
                            <a href="vehicleinservice" class="nav-link" @onclick="OnVehicleInServiceClick">
                                <i class="nav-icon fas fa-edit"></i>
                                <p>
                                    Has-a-submenu-list
                                    <span class="badge badge-info right">@vehicleInServiceCount.VehicleInServiceCount</span>
                                </p>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="takingintoservice" class="nav-link">
                                        <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                        <p>111111111r</p>
                                        <span class="badge badge-info right">@vehicleInServiceCount.TakingIntoServiceCount</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="inmaintenance" class="nav-link">
                                        <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                        <p>222222222</p>
                                        <span class="badge badge-info right">@vehicleInServiceCount.InMaintenanceCount</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="waitingsparepart" class="nav-link">
                                        <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                        <p>3333333333</p>
                                        <span class="badge badge-info right">@vehicleInServiceCount.WaitingSparePartCount</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="readytodeliver" class="nav-link">
                                        <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                        <p>4444444</p>
                                        <span class="badge badge-info right">@vehicleInServiceCount.ReadyToDeliveryCount</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="delivered" class="nav-link">
                                        <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                        <p>55555555</p>
                                        <span class="badge badge-info right">@vehicleInServiceCount.DeliveredCount</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>



            
            <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="customercard" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-user-tie"></i>
                        <p>
                            XYZ
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
                    <a href="invoice" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-layer-group"></i>
                        <p>
                            A
                            <i class="fas fa-angle-left right"></i>
                        </p>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="stockcard" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>A1</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="stocksale" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>A2</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="stockpurchase" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>A3</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
                    <a href="invoice" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-receipt"></i>
                        <p>
                            B
                            <i class="fas fa-angle-left right"></i>
                        </p>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="invoiceinbound" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>B1</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="invoiceoutbound" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>B2</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tools"></i>
                        <p>
                            C
                            <i class="fas fa-angle-left right"></i>
                        </p>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="safeaccount" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fas fa-lira-sign nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>C1</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="staff" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fas fa-industry nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>C2</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="users" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fas fa-users nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>C3</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="firminfo" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fas fa-industry nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>C4</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The overlap happens as the li elements you expand are taken out of the content/document flow, while the other lis A B C etc. are not.

Technically you are not expanding them rather show/hiding them.
Here is the MDN article:
[Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

You either would've to "put them back" into the content flow by using `position: relative`, for example, or by shifting the other elements downwards with a `padding-top`. The second solution wouldn't be my first choice, though.